# Error in Selenium IDE, receiving error "Element id=ui-id-12 not found"

Tags: element

In Selenium I recorded a test suite and while executing I received the script error:

> Element id=ui-id-12 not found

Comment: Please explain your question in detail like what you are testing , what script is generated?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have recorded wrong script. The element ID 12 is changing every time. So you can use another way to detect the Web-Element.You will have to use more preferred way of locating the Web-element. Instead of using id please try to use static attribute of the Web-Element. I believe it will fix your problem.